# Collapse or expand multiple tables at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following code as a sample `HTML` file.

```
<table border=0>
    <tr class="RowToClick"><td>Click Here to Toggle Dataset 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>

<table border=0>
    <tr class="RowToClick"><td>Click Here to Toggle Dataset 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>

<table border=0>  
    <tr class="RowToClick"><td>Click Here to Toggle Dataset 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I would like to have a text such as Collapse/expand All to do the work at the same time for all of tables. I know how can I do for only one table using JavaScript but do know how to do it for all tables.

May I ask if anyone knows how to do it?

**Update:**

Here is the code for the collapsing/expanding one table:

```
/*Jscript*/
function ShowHide(obj){
    var tbody = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var old = tbody.style.display;
    tbody.style.display = (old == "none"?"":"none");
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to collapse/expand the table?

Comment: @n0m4d please see the update part.

Comment: @Saber, that is only a function declaration, you need to show us where and how you call it. Stackoverflow allows you to include executable HTML/Javascript code snippets, so just create a snippet showing your current attempt. Also explain whether you want to hide the complete table or only the rows after the clickable row.

Comment: @Saber how do you bind the ShowHide? My best guess is that the problem might be related to the line `obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]`. You are filtering only the first (index at position 0) table by its tag body.

Comment: @Saber check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/G7MVh2HVADDS1gXbiQBP?p=preview) example I made. See if this is what you want.

Comment: @n0m4d Thanks for your answer. But it is not collapse all tables at the same time, right? What I want is collapse all and expand all. Thanks!

Comment: @Saber apologies for forgetting the collapse/expand all. I changed the other version with a new one [check](https://plnkr.co/edit/0AI5Byz8ThEBh3NH779T?p=preview) it out.

Comment: @n0m4d Thanks for your modification. But now all table will be collapse as one table. I mean I would like to have all `Click Here to Toggle Dataset ...` (remain) when one click on the `Expand all/ Collapse all`.

Comment: And I noticed that the `for loop` is not working for me. It seems to be as C++/CS style rather than JavaScript, right?